# I want to make an animation with images in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, image, sprite

i want to make an animation on c# with picturebox, i have an sprite 470px 135px and i want to start the picturebox with the first 71px of width and keep the height, and after that, i want to make an while to replace the previous 71px to the next 71px with.

so i want to make an animation replacing an frame of an image with a new one.
here is the image.[image]

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to either use GDI+ and draw on a panel/form or use another tool for the job (DirectX, etc..). Don't use a picturebox. GDI+ - System.Drawing actually - is quite ok, but for real animation, try using another framework. I don't know the full use case ofcourse, so mlaybe you could tell us what you're working on? As a start, look into this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409988/Beginners-Starting-a-D-Game-with-GDIplus

Comment: its an animation. for a tic -tac-toe game. when you win it display this animaiton

Comment: Why don't you try a game framework like unity, that way updating sprites is made easy

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise you to either use [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and draw on a panel/form or use another tool for the job (DirectX, etc..). Don't use a picturebox, as it will make it very difficult to track object and is not good performancewise when there are a lot more objects on screen. It will also make it more difficult to draw backgrounds, do collision detection, etc..

[GDI+ - System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) actually - is quite ok, but for real animation, try using another framework.

As a start, look into this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/409988/Beginners-Starting-a-D-Game-with-GDIplus - whcihc explains how to write a game with GDI+.

You can also look into specialised tools/frameworks such as [Unity2D](http://unity3d.com/pages/2d-power), or [Otter2D](http://otter2d.com/). These are frameworks that do take up a bit more time learning how to work with them, but are far more powerful to create a game, and hand you some best practices and principles to ensure good performance and structure.

Comment: for the ones downvoting, it would help if you actually correct the answer, or let people know what's wrong, in stead of just clicking a button!

Answer (score -1):

You could use Graphics class instead of an imageBox and call the function Graphics.DrawImage giving a rectangle and update the rectangle X in each interaction
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142041(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile("angryBird.jpg");

// Create coordinates for upper-left corner of image.
int x = 100;
int y = 100;

// Create rectangle for source image.
Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 71, 71);
GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

// Draw image to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, srcRect, units);
```

Comment: Yes you can, but I fear for a game - as he wishes to create - this is not best practice. It's too complex if you'd want to render 10 to 20 objects on screen, or even backgrounds etc... There are better solutions for the problem at hand I feel.

Comment: I agree that is better for him to use a game framework to do that, but I think if he was looking for that kind of solution he probably would not try to start with an ImageBox...